# find files then parse the results before displaying the results

Tags: vb.net, linq, getfiles

I'm working on an app for our customer service division.  The user will enter a print number, and a mfg date.  the app will then do a get files returning results of all files found with that drawing number (multiple revisions). the files are named in this format `drawingnumber_rev_pages_6-digit date.pdf`.
Once I have the list of that drawing number, I then take a right(string) of 10 characters to strip the 6-digit date off, and do a `Date.ParseExact` to compare to the user input mfg date.  I was grabbing anything prior to that date, and showing them in a listbox.  the criteria has now changed, and they want me to only show the file that would pertain to that build date.  The problem is, I need the first rev prior to that date.  and I don't fully understand the (function) portion of my getfiles statement.  So I don't know what to search for to even lookup google results.  as I search for getfiles, function isn't mentioned, if I look up orderby... function isn't mentioned, is it linq I need to search under?  how would you propose I approach this?
[original version example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LM2ps.jpg)
new version, I can filter result and find everything before date ... but what I want is the highest revision before the mfg. date.  return a single result.
[current version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFqt5.jpg)

thank you all-  here's my sample code.

```
Try
    Dim results = Directory.GetFiles(fp, f).
        OrderByDescending(Function(x) New FileInfo(x).FullName)

    For Each result In results
        Dim dp As String = ""
        Dim d As Date
        dp = Strings.Right(result, 10)
        dp = Strings.Left(dp, 6)
        d = Date.ParseExact(dp, "MMddyy", New Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us"))
        Debug.Print(dp)
        Debug.Print(d)
        Dim udt As String = ""
        Dim ud As Date 'user date
        udt = Trim(Replace(txtMfgDate.Text, "/", ""))
        If udt.ToString.Length = 0 Then lstFound.Items.Add(result)

        ud = Date.ParseExact(udt, "MMddyy", New Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us"))
        If d.Date <= ud.Date Then
            lstFound.Items.Add(result)
        End If

        Debug.Print(d)
        Debug.Print(ud)
        If result <> Nothing Then

        End If
    Next
Catch x As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Error finding file: " & f)
End Try
```

Comment: The `OrderByDescending` doesn't make sense because you could use the file-path directly, so: `Directory.GetFiles(fp, f).OrderByDescending(Function(path) path)`. If you can't use LINQ, you need .NET 3.5, Vuisual Studio 2008 and `Imports System.Linq`.

Comment: I'm using .net 4.5.2 and writing the code using visual studio 2015.
I'm self taught, and found the getfiles sample using the function portion of the statement - I used to use it to grab the last modified date, but that doesn't reflect the actual revision date - so I had to modify it.  I mentioned linQ, because I wasn't sure if the function portion was a linq statement or not.  I haven't been able to find documentation on that portion of the getfiles line in my code - and I don't fully understand how that works.

Comment: The orderby was there from where I use it in other areas of code where I find the first instance to grab the latest revision.  production and bill writers use this app too.  Bad copy/paste practice on my part.

Comment: What is the error-message exactly? Show also the stacktrace (which mentions line numbers and methods).

Comment: There is no error.  let me rephrase.  I'm searching for a file like this.  User enters drawing number 0.071.911  currently app returns all revisions.  0071911_a_1_072115.pdf, 0071911_b_1_091115.pdf, etc.
customer service has a warranty or call, they want to enter a date as part of the search criteria.  customer unit mfg date was 7/1/15.  I want to then find and only show rev A, as rev b was made after the customers version.  if the date was 6/1/17 - it would return rev F in this case, not rev a thru F... my first attempt I was only returning those before the date, but they want 1 file.

Comment: well, i still havent fully understood the requirement, i'm missing some menaingful samples and desired results. But `OrderByDescending` is LINQ and not related to `GetFiles`, which is a method in `System.IO.File` that returns all files(paths) of a given directory-path. Instead of editing your comment you should edit your question to clarify it and to provide some sample-files, sample-input and what you expect.

Comment: I've added screen shots to help clarify.  this finds a file on the server so the user doesn't have to navigate the paths.  for customer service they want to find the correct print based on what print was active when the product was built.  they input a drawing number and a date.  the app needs to return the highest rev prior to that date matching the drawing number.  does that help?

Comment: Probably not much help as you may not have control over the naming convention... but it would be easier if the date portion of the file was YYMMDD format. Sorting in decending order on the filename would be easier.

Comment: Keep in mind that we do not know the business rules and such which makes it difficult to understand what you want (or *perhaps* offer a better solution).  Even the example in comments seems off.  Item `0.071.911` for `07/01/2011` would seem not to be either `A` or `b` because `07/21/2015` (A) is also after `07/01/2011` - both seem to be after the desired date.  Its also not clear what *function* you are talking about in the actual post. A function other than `GetFiles()`?

Comment: engineering prints change periodically for model year, or production improvements.  with this app, customer service is trying to find the correct print that would have been active at the time the unit was built. the file format is drawing number(no decimals)_rev letter_page count_6-digitdate.pdf -- always. rev a was 6/28/15, rev b was 7/10/15.  unit was built 7/1 - app needs to find rev a print. as example

Answer (score 0):

LINQ can do everything you need with the right conditions. I also tried to clean up some of the code in other ways. I switched the LINQ expression to query comprehension to so I could use `Let`.

```
Try
    Dim enusCulture = New Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us") ' consider CultureInfo.CurrentCulture instead?
    Dim udt As String = Trim(Replace(txtMfgDate.Text, "/", ""))
    Dim ud As Date

    If udt.Length > 0 Then ud = Date.ParseExact(udt, "MMddyy", enusCulture) ' user mfg date
    ' 0071911_a_1_072115.pdf

    Dim results = From filename In Directory.GetFiles(fp, f)
        Let filedate = Date.ParseExact(filename.Substring(filename.Length - 10, 6), "MMddyy", enusCulture)
        Where udt.Length = 0 OrElse filedate.Date < ud.Date
        Order By filedate Descending

    If udt.Length> 0 Then
        results = results.Take(1)
    End If

    lstFound.Items.AddRange(results)
Catch x As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Error finding file: " & f)
End Try
```

The `Function(x)` syntax is a lambda expression, and it is part of LINQ method syntax for the `OrderByDescending` function, if you want to research that.

Comment: thank you for the reply - and explaining that is a lambda expression, I will search that and read up on it.  in the meantime - I will try your code modification.  giving credit - thank you-

Comment: the code solution above did not work and doesn't find any file.  the error is something about the date not being in the format of the calendar?  something I've never seen before.

Comment: I think there is an error in the logic. Let me fix it.

Comment: I think I had a typo in the `ud` assignment. Otherwise that error should only occur if a filename has the wrong format.